Wherein Padma Purana is this verse found and is this authentic?
ṣaṭ-karma-nipuṇo vipro
mantra-tantra-viśāradaḥ
avaiṣṇavo gurur na syād
vaiṣṇavaḥ śvapaco guruḥ
Can someone point me the chapter and verse number.

It may not be present in the manuscripts for which the translation is available online but may still be authentic.
